# Chrome OS Not Booting

Tags: boot, usb, google-chrome-os

I've been trying to install Chrome OS on my flash drive through Hexxeh's builds. Every time I put it on my flash drive and reboot my computer I select to boot with my USB and a screen comes up with some bios style menu that says "up or down arrow to select file" and " F10 to PowerOff" And some other things. It has a space that looks like it should have files to select but there's nothing there. I've tries to USB thumb drives now and neither have worked. It also always corrupts them so I use diskaprt and fix them and I always format them through fat32. Is that the problem? Should I be using NTFS or something?

I'm using Windows 8.1 and I have a BIOSTAR A960A3+ (A9) Motherboard.

Comment: The install process for hexxeh's chromeos should end up overwriting whatever partitioning you're using - you *are* using image writer, as per the instructions, right?

Comment: Yes I do happen to be using Win32 Disk Imager and I'm running it under administrator.